# Find the latest rows by filtering the status

Tags: mysql

I have a table called person_list. The data is,

```
Insert into person_list(person_allocation_id, person_id, created_datetime, boss_user_name, allocation_status_id) values
(111008, 1190016, '2021-01-05 11:09:25', 'Rajesh', '2'),
(111007, 1190015, '2020-12-12 09:23:31', 'Sushmita', '2'),
(111006, 1190014, '2020-12-11 10:48:26', '', '3'),
(111005, 1190014, '2020-12-10 13:46:15', 'Rangarao', '2'),
(111004, 1190014, '2020-12-10 13:36:10', '', '3');
```

Here person_allocation_id is the primary key.

person_id may be duplicated some times.

All of these rows are sorted by person_allocation_id (in descending order)

Now, I would like to filter the rows which are having allocation_status_id = '2' and boss_user_name should be non-empty for the person_id.

The difficulty here is that I have to exclude the row if the person_id is having allocation_status_id = '3' as their latest status (according to date).

I am unable to understand how could I compare the dates in one row with another in the previous row.

So finally I should get only 2 rows in my final result set (person_allocation_id are 111008 and 111007).

Somehow I achieved this in Oracle.

```
select person_id, person_allocation_id, create_datetime, boss_user_name, allocation_status_id 
from (
select person_id, person_allocation_id, create_datetime, boss_user_name, allocation_status_id, 
       rank() over (partition by person_id order by create_datetime desc) rnk
from person_list 
where allocation_status_id = '2') 
where rnk = 1;
```

But, I need this for MySql DB. Anyone, please help?

Thanks.

Comment: *But, I need this for MySql DB* What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: the MySql DB version is 5.7.24-27

Comment: *Somehow I achieved this in Oracle.* ?? this query must return 3 rows, not 2 - it checks neither the row is latest nor boss name column is set.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM person_list t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(t2.person_allocation_id) person_allocation_id, t2.person_id
       FROM person_list t2
       GROUP BY t2.person_id ) t3 USING (person_allocation_id, person_id)
WHERE t1.allocation_status_id = '2'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d518a784d7ea474f971a34f2ed7a84c6)

Add more conditions to WHERE clause if needed (for example, `AND boss_user_name != ''`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the latest `allocation_status_id` value per `person_id`:

```
select person_allocation_id   
   , person_id
   , created_datetime
   , boss_user_name
   , allocation_status_id
from (   
   select person_allocation_id   
      , person_id
      , created_datetime
      , boss_user_name
      , allocation_status_id
      , (select pl2.allocation_status_id
         from person_list pl2
         where pl2.person_id = pl.person_id
         order by pl2.created_datetime desc
         limit 1) latest_allocation_status_id
from person_list pl) t
where 
   allocation_status_id = '2' and latest_allocation_status_id <> '3' 
     and boss_user_name <> ''
```

The outer query is able to check the latest status and return the expected result set. The query works for MySQL 5.7

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a903ca/4)

As a side note, for MySQL 8.0 you can replace the correlated subquery with a window function:

```
last_value(allocation_status_id) over (partition by person_id 
                                       order by created_datetime desc)
```

[Demo for window function](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6274882c1055e99e28ea2219ba3c8d5b)